# How to get the enclosing method node with JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

When I have a method foo() that calls bar(), how can I get the foo() AST node from MethodInvocation node (or whatever statements/expressions in the method)? For example, I need to know the IMethod foo from b.bar().

```
public void foo()
{
    b.bar();
}
```

Comment: I think that is in fact the canonical way to get the enclosing method of a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDT/UI we have a helper method to do this. Take a look at `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.ASTNodes.getParent(ASTNode, int)`

Comment: Which dependency needs to be added for this ? Also , is this available in version 3.5 ?

Comment: You need org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin. I have not checked but this method probably predates 3.5.

Comment: +1, It works !! `ASTNode parentNode = ASTNodes.getParent(methodInvocationNode, ASTNode.METHOD_DECLARATION);`

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this code, but I expect there are better ways to get the result.

```
public static IMethod getMethodThatInvokesThisMethod(MethodInvocation node) {
    ASTNode parentNode = node.getParent();
    while (parentNode.getNodeType() != ASTNode.METHOD_DECLARATION) {
        parentNode = parentNode.getParent();
    }

    MethodDeclaration md = (MethodDeclaration) parentNode;
    IBinding binding = md.resolveBinding();
    return (IMethod)binding.getJavaElement();
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. This is almost same as what we use in JDT/UI.

Answer (score 0):

The other trick might be letting the visitor store the caller information before visiting the MethodInvocation node:

```
ASTVisitor visitor = new ASTVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        String caller = node.getName().toString();
        System.out.println("CALLER: " + caller);

        return true;
    }
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
        String methodName = node.getName().toString();
        System.out.println("INVOKE: " + methodName);
```

With AnotherClass Type:

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public int getValue()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public int moved(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x > 30)
            return getValue();
        else
            return getValue();
    }
}
```

I could get the information:

```
TYPE(CLASS): AnotherClass
CALLER: getValue
CALLER: moved
INVOKE: getValue
INVOKE: getValue
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the main use case is to inspect the method declaration from one class called in another class. This is only useful when the caller class is also the declaring class.