# Get enclosing of statement node using jdt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have a method foo() that has some statement in below. How to get enclose statement `ASTNode` (or whatever statement) from the body ?

For example I want to know how to get `if` from method invocation, get `for` from `if` statement.

for e.g

```
public void foo()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(i==1)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

result :

```
System.out.println(i) --> if(i==1)
if(i==1) --> for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the enclosing method node with JDT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449262/how-to-get-the-enclosing-method-node-with-jdt)

Comment: my post updated. his case using methodinvoke to method, can apllying in my case ??

Comment: give it try to see if it works

Comment: please, i'm beginner using JDT, do you have any example ???

Answer (score 1):

In this case `if` is enclosed by `for` i.e `for` is parent of `if`.

So on ASTNode of `if` statement, if you call ASTNode.getParent() you will get the `for` statement.

Comment: no, it will printed out all of block parent. and i have try using `if(node instanceof ForStatement)` but it cannot.

Comment: if you want to print only ` for(int i=0;i<4;i++)` you have to construct the string manually. ForStatement.initializers() will give you the initializer list. ForStatement.getExpression() will give you the condition expression. ForStatement.updaters() will give you the updater list. With this you can build your string

Comment: can you make some example, i'm sorry, i'm actually still beginner using JDT. please.

Comment: Suppose 'astNode' is the ASTNode of is statement try doing System.out.println(astNode.getParent.toString.split("{")[0]);  It may solve your probem

Comment: this is still not print parent statement.